# Pods - display link to relationship post

Tags: php, wordpress, relationship, podscms

I'm using Pods to set up Custom Post Types in WordPress.

I have two custom post types: Car and Garage. In Car I have set up a relationship field with Garage, so when editing a Car post I can select one of the Garage posts available from the drop-down.

When viewing a Car post, I would like to display the name and the link to the garage post selected. How would I do that?

Below is an example from http://pods.io/tutorials/get-values-from-a-custom-relationship-field

```
//get Pods object for current post
$pod = pods( 'pod_name', get_the_id() );
//get the value for the relationship field
$related = $pod->field( 'relationship_field' );
//loop through related field, creating links to their own pages
//only if there is anything to loop through
if ( ! empty( $related ) ) {
    foreach ( $related as $rel ) { 
        //get id for related post and put in ID
        //for advanced content types use $id = $rel[ 'id' ];
        $id = $rel[ 'ID' ];
        //show the related post name as link
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a>';
        //get the value for some_field in related post and echo it
    } //end of foreach
} //endif ! empty ( $related )
```

Instead of a permalink to a Garage post, I'm getting several permalinks to the Car post I'm viewing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I just replied to your cross-post in our forums. Either here or there, you need to show us your actual code, not the example code pasted from my tutorial to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! Commented on the forum.